# My png image in Image.Source is not supported by Blend (XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I try to show an `Image` in my WPF application and added the following code:

```
<Image Height="20" Width="20" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="pack://application:/Testapp.Model/Resources/Icons/systemEnviromentActor.png"/>
```

However I get the error that blend does not support this type of Image. Microsofts page says that `Image` does support `.png`.

I created the Image with Paint.net

Comment: There aren't *nearly* enough commas in that URI for it to be valid :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URI is invalid. A valid [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris) would look like shown below, where `Testapp.Model` is an assembly name.

```
pack://application:,,,/Testapp.Model;component/Resources/Icons/systemEnviromentActor.png
```

If the image file is in the same assembly, you could write it as

```
pack://application:,,,/Resources/Icons/systemEnviromentActor.png
```

In XAML, you could then even omit the prefix, and just write

```
Source="/Resources/Icons/systemEnviromentActor.png"
```

Also make sure that the Build Action of the image file is set to `Resource`.

Comment: Thought the commas were supposed to be replaced with your own path.
Changing Buold Action to Resource made it work. Thank you very much Clemens!